# How do I update a nested Item in a different reducer (slice) with redux toolkit in a React app

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have the following code (I deleted most of it to make it easier to understand - but everything works):

"role" reducer:

```
 // some async thunks      
        
   const rolesSlice = createSlice({
           name: "role",
           initialState,
           reducers: { // some reducers here  },
           extraReducers: {
             // a bunch of extraReducers
             [deleteRole.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
               state.roles = state.roles.filter((role) => role._id !== payload.id);
               state.loading = false;
               state.hasErrors = false;
             },
           },
         });
export const rolesSelector = (state) => state.roles;

export default rolesSlice.reducer;
```

"scene" reducer:

```
    // some async thunks
    
    const scenesSlice = createSlice({
      name: "scene",
      initialState,
      reducers: {},
      extraReducers: {
        [fetchScenes.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
          state.scenes = payload.map((scene) => scene);
          state.loading = false;
          state.scenesFetched = true;
        }
    }

export const scenesSelector = (state) => state.scenes;

export default scenesSlice.reducer;
```

a component with a button and a handleDelete function:

```
// a react functional component

function handleDelete(role) {

 // some confirmation code

      dispatch(deleteRole(role._id));
  }
```

My scene model (and store state) looks like this:

```
   [
    {
     number: 1,
     roles: [role1, role2]
    },
    {
    number: 2,
    roles: [role3, role5]
    }
   ]
```

What I am trying to achieve is, when a role gets deleted, the state.scenes gets updated (map over the scenes and filter out every occurrence of the deleted role).

So my question is, how can I update the state without calling two different actions from my component (which is the recommended way for that?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `extraReducers` property of `createSlice` to respond to actions which are defined in another slice, or which are defined outside of the slice as they are here.

You want to iterate over every scene and remove the deleted role from the roles array.  If you simply replace every single array with its filtered version that's the easiest to write.  But it will cause unnecessary re-renders because some of the arrays that you are replacing are unchanged.  Instead we can use `.findIndex()` and `.splice()`, similar to [this example](https://github.com/immerjs/immer/issues/115).

```
extraReducers: {
  [fetchScenes.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => { ... }
  [deleteRole.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
    state.scenes.forEach( scene => {
      // find the index of the deleted role id in an array of ids
      const i = scene.roles.findIndex( id => id === payload.id );
      // if the array contains the deleted role
      if ( i !== -1 ) {
        // remove one element starting from that position
        scene.roles.splice( i, 1 )
      }
    })
  }
}
```